# Terminal command to change Privilege of "everyone" to "No Access"

Tags: macos, terminal, permission

I want to change the privilege of a specific folder for the "everyone" group to No Access. I have tried chmod o--- that doesnt seem to work but I am most likely doing it wrong. I know that If I click "get info" I can manually adjust it but I want to be able to do it in Terminal so I can deploy this command to numerous Macs. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chmod 700 /path/to/folder` should do the trick for you. This allows execute (1), write (2), and read (4) for the owner, and no access for everyone else.